# How to cache npm dependencies in GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions

Below is my dockerfile. Is there a way to cache npm in GitHub action?

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
ADD package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

My GitHub actions:

```
name: NPM buid

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build-npm-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Build and Tag Node image
        id: build-ui-image
        run: |
          export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
          docker build -t ui -f ./ui/Dockerfile .
```

P.S I don't want to cache docker image. Above docker file is used just for example. objection is cache npm dependencies

Comment: `setup-node` can cache the dependencies as of v2: https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-packages-dependencies. But that's if you're building in GitHub Actions, **not** in a Docker container. Why ar you showing your Dockerfile; what does your _pipeline_ actually look like?

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with [actions/setup-node@v3](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-global-packages-data)

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: current
    cache: npm
- name: Build and Tag Node image
  id: build-ui-image
  run: |
    export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    docker build -t ui -f ./ui/Dockerfile .
```

Answer (score 1):

Caching npm dependencies will not make a difference if you're building a docker image. You can use [`actions/setup-node`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) for caching JS or [`docker/build-push-action`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) for Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check below action ?
[actions/cache@v2](https://github.com/actions/cache)

So your Actions yaml would look like below,

```
name: NPM buid

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build-npm-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - name: Caching node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: "app/node_modules"
          key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('app/package.json') }}
      - name: Build and Tag Node image
        id: build-ui-image
        run: |
          export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
          docker build -t ui -f ./ui/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: I don't think it will work because the path we are caching is app/node_modules but the npm command is going to run inside the docker.

Comment: What we can do is, build in GitHub actions itself since we will have node_modules cached, and copy dist folder in our Dockerfile, so that you don't have to run npm ci inside Dockerfile again.